# How to extend initWithWindowNibName for an NSWindowController?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm not sure I am using the correct terminology, but I want to extend and existing method for a class. I want to be able to call

```
[[CustomWindowViewController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Something" withObject:object];
```

I want to implement all of the default functionality, of initWithWindowNibName, but then also pass the object as well.

Thanks

Chet

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

```
- (id)initWithWindowNibName:(NSString *)windowNibName withObject:(NSObject*)object {

    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:windowNibName];
    // custom stuff

    return self;
}
```